# Firebase Emulator start with 2 realtime databases?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

When starting the emulator I see 2 databases in the realtime database emulator. One with `<project id>` and the other `<project id>-default-rtdb` .

[image]

Can anybody explain or reference some docs on why this is?

---

This is my setup files

> firebase.json

```json
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

> functions/package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: How did you configure things when you ran `firebase init`?  What features did you select, and did you create a new project/use an existing project/or no project?

Comment: @Iguananaut I have added the setup files to the question.

Comment: All I could find was [this code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/44ae32e26e8bae614a698c586b5b35344554a3b3/src/init/features/database.ts#L77) in `firebase init` which, when setting up a project with Realtime Database enabled, will create a default database named `<projectId>-default-rtdb`.  What's mysterious about this is, if the project already exists and already has a database, it shouldn't be creating the default one.  But I don't think the emulator code is all open source, so we may never be able to be sure.  I think it might be a bug.

Comment: @Iguananaut thank you for taking a look and trying to make sense of it. I thought I had done something wrong

Comment: I don't think you did.  I was able to reproduce this problem with a brand new `demo-` project.  It's weird.

Comment: Same problem here. At least I know I'm not the only one experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I just figured it out. Adding a `"database"` section to the top level of the `firebase.json` file makes the emulator create 2 databases. Additionally, if the name of the project in `.firebaserc` starts with demo **AND** there's a `"database"` section added to the top level of your `firebase.json` file then there will be 3 total `Realtime Database`s created.

So, having a `firebase.json` file that looks like this:

```js
{ "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

and a `.firebaserc` file that looks like this:

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "demo-MyProject-development"
  }
}
```

results in 3 databases being created.

I've decided that that I'm going to go without adding the rules file to my `firebase.json` (thus removing the `"database"` section from the file) and writing the rules manually into the browser.

My files now look like this:

`firebase.json`

```js
{ 
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

`.firebaserc`

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "MyProject-development"
  }
}
```

Comment: that makes you avoid getting 3 but still getting 2 databases instead of just 1 in you emulator, right?